# Ios app automation using a simulator

Tags: java, ios, macos, selenium, appium

```
public static AppiumDriver wd;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("appium-version", "1.0");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformversion", "8.3");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone5");
    // capabilities.setCapability("app", "CustomFurnish");
    File appDir = new File("\\Users\\cloudgust\\dev\\bluebox\\iphone-app\\CustomFurnish.xcodeproj");
    File app = new File(appDir, "CustomFurnish.xcodeproj");
    //File file = new File("/Users/cloudgust/dev/bluebox/iphone-app/CustomFurnish.xcodeproj");
    capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
    wd = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
```

When I give the above and run the project my console shows an error

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Bad app: /Users/cloudgust/Documents/workspace/iosautomation/\Users\cloudgust\dev\bluebox\iphone-app\CustomFurnish.xcodeproj/CustomFurnish.xcodeproj. App paths need to be absolute, or relative to the appium server install dir, or a URL to compressed file, or a special app name. cause: Error: Using local app, but didn't end in .zip, .ipa or .app) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information).

Basically what I'm trying to do is I have app written in xcode on a mac , I want to run it in automated tests using appium . but when im doing it I encounter with tat error. can someone please help .

TIA,
Sampath

Answer (score 0):

This might be because the path of the ios app you provided in File appDir doesn't end with .app or .ipa extension. It must contain the path up to the application code with extension .ipa or .app.

Answer (score 0):

You must build the project and generate a .app file, then point appium to that path.

To build on command line you can use xcodebuild

Here are some example of command like arguments and such: [Apple xcodebuild](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html)